# Storing Business Logic in Tables rather than Stored Procedure or Application

Tags: database-design

The requirement is that once the product has been delivered, user can update the logic as he wants.

An example of logic I have is follows-

An institute teaches English has following requirements -

1. At the time of registration student can choose either **Writing** or **Reading** or both.
2. Student can choose **Speaking** only if it is being offered in the same Term as well as it is starting within 2 weeks.

Applying this logic in the application or stored procedure is fairly simple. But as per requirements, above scenario could change.

How can we achieve something like above.

Comment: "The requirement is that once the product has been delivered, user can update the logic as he wants." - sell them SQL Server, Management Studio, and a load of training. *Or*, find out what their *actual* requirements are.